# Armature physics

Tags: armature, physics

I'm trying to add physics to this armature so that it will be able to swing when it is moved. Does anyone know of any tutorials or solutions? (Images are to demonstrate how the mesh is supposed to move.) [image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question this video might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c11l2o5uCQs

It shows a method for adding physics to a rig by tying it to a simple cloth simulation

This is the method i use

Comment: In a few words, what does it show?

Comment: good point i will fix it

Answer (score 0):

I found a very interesting addon called **SPRING BONES** for this purpose: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hh7CT0n8KN4

I used it on a few rigs for very simple hair or tail dynamics and it worked pretty well for my needs.

You can get it from Github: https://github.com/artellblender/springbones

Do this only, when you're done with your primary animations:

1. in Pose Mode go to Pose -> Animation -> **Bake Action**.
2. Hit "OK".
3. Go to Dope Sheet -> **Action Editor**. Now you should have an Action (CubeAction f.E) with your main primary animation, and a **new Action** in your list. Rename them properly to keep order.
4. Select your **new Action** and hit the **"Push Down"** button. This creates a new strip in the **Non Linear Animation Editor** (NLA-Editor). There you can stack multiple Actions and also edit their timing.
5. Go to NLA-Editor and pull your new Action below your primary Action. They should have the same length. Make sure to turn on all checkboxes on your Armature strip, so all the action strips will be evaluated to the final result.